# ReadProcessMemory on a 64 bit proces always returns Error 299

Tags: c++, windows, msdn, readprocessmemory

I'm having some trouble with ReadProcessMemory 
My code is 64 bit 
I can read the memory of any 32 bit process , but ReadProcessMemory always fails with error code 299 (Partial read) returning 0 bytes read.

Done my research and most answers were relate to privilges , but I have Debugging token enabled and running as admin , The address i read the the ImageBase in the PE optional header

I tried to check the page status using VirtualQueryEx and got access denied!

Note : The code runs perfectly on any 32 bit process.

Any Ideas what maybe be causing this ?

```
HANDLE hProcess;
DWORD pid;
EnableDebugPriv();
pid=GetProcessByName("winmine.exe"); //32 bit apps work
//pid=GetProcessByName("notepad.exe"); //64 bit apps dont
hProcess = OpenProcess(PROCESS_ALL_ACCESS ,0, pid);
if(!hProcess)
{
    printf("failed to acquire handle , Error %d \n" , GetLastError());
    return FAILED;
}


//DEBUGGING
//DWORD address =   0x100000000; //64 notepad
DWORD address =  0x1000000; // 32 bit minsweeper
DWORD oldProtect=0;
printf("DEBUG pid %d - last err :%d \n" , GetProcessId(hProcess) , GetLastError() );
if(VirtualProtectEx(hProcess , (LPVOID)address,4096 /*pagesize for test*/ , PAGE_EXECUTE_READWRITE , &oldProtect))
{
    cout <<"vp done \n";
}
else cout << " vp err :" << GetLastError() << endl;
PMEMORY_BASIC_INFORMATION pmbi = new MEMORY_BASIC_INFORMATION;
if(VirtualQueryEx(hProcess,(LPVOID)address,pmbi,sizeof(MEMORY_BASIC_INFORMATION)))
{
    cout << "protection :" << pmbi->AllocationProtect << endl;
}
char value = 0;
SIZE_T * pbytes = new SIZE_T ;
ReadProcessMemory(hProcess,(LPCVOID)address ,&value,sizeof(value),pbytes);
cout << value << endl;
printf("Read status : %d ; bytes read %d  \n",GetLastError() , *pbytes );
CloseHandle(hProcess);
```

Comment: any code will help us alot on fixing the issue

Comment: Might try using `uintptr_t` rather than `DWORD` to store the address as in a 64-bit process a pointer is 8 bytes and `DWORD` is 4.

Comment: tried that and still getting the same result , thanks though :(

Comment: So after some debugging and research it turned out the problem was with ASLR so i was reading from a wrong base , thanks for the help :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

So after some debugging and research it turned out the problem was with ASLR so i was reading from a wrong base , thanks for the help :)

Comment: I know it's been a while, but how did you overcome this issue?  I'm having the same problem.

Comment: The fixed base address 0x100000000 was incorrect due to ASLR (address randomization) so the base address changes every run,  you should retrive the base address every time rather than just hardcoding it.
I cant really remember how i did it , it has been a while but i am sure you will figure it out with some research..Good luck!

Comment: Ah... that's what I was figuring, but wasn't sure that's what you meant.  I was able to do it dynamically using [GetModuleInformation](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms683201(v=vs.85).aspx)

Comment: I don't even know if you still use this page, but I cannot thank you enough!

Answer (score 3):

Just using `MEMORY_BASIC_INFORMATION` like that is incorrect. You should use either use `MEMORY_BASIC_INFORMATION32` or `MEMORY_BASIC_INFORMATION64` (as described in the [remarks section](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa366775(v=vs.85).aspx) in the MSDN) depending on whether the remote process is 32bit or 64bit.

The size and layout of the structure will be different depending on whether it's a 32bit or a 64bit process. By just using `MEMORY_BASIC_INFORMATION` you expect that the remote process uses whatever layout your current process uses.

In order to test whether the remote process is 32bit or 64bit you can use the [`IsWow64Process`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms684139(v=vs.85).aspx) function like this:

```
bool is64BitProcess(HANDLE hProcess)
{
    const bool is64BitOS = sizeof(void *) == 8 || IsWow64Process(GetCurrentProcess());
    return is64BitOS ? IsWow64Process(hProcess)
                     : false;
}
```

Comment: I know it is a 64 bit process no need to test , this was just for debugging purposes and will be removed from the code when i know why i can't read the 64 bit processes memory .. the code is going to be  for a specific 64 bit process it's not generic those are just test cases