# Calling VirtualQueryEx function from a 64 bit process on a 32 bit one

Tags: windows, winapi, 32bit-64bit

**TL;DR:** If I call `VirtualQueryEx` on a 32 bit process from a 64 bit process, should I use `MEMORY_BASIC_INFORMATION` or `MEMORY_BASIC_INFORMATION32` ?

Hi!

I have a 64 bit application that reads other processes' memory (`OpenProcess`, `VirtualQueryEx` and then `ReadProcessMemory`). I was wondering if I should do a special check to see if the other process is a 32 bit one.

My code is something like this:

```
MEMORY_BASIC_INFORMATION info;

SIZE_T r = VirtualQueryEx((HANDLE) handle,
(void *) 0x0,
&info,
sizeof(info));
```

The thing is, [the documentation of MEMORY_BASIC_INFORMATION](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa366775%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) says this:

> To enable a debugger to debug a target that is running on a different
>   architecture (32-bit versus 64-bit), use one of the explicit forms of
>   this structure.

The two processes are running on the same computer (same architecture?) but one is a 32 bit process and the other a 64 bit one.

I have tested this app in 64 bit windows 8 and it works for my test cases (searching specific strings in a 32 bit process memory), but I don't want it to backfire later.

**NOTE**: I am aware of [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/20069140/284906), and that's why I am asking this question in the first place. I tested with 32 bit binaries and it just works without errors.

Comment: No, the debugger function they are talking about is [this one](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/hardware/ff553502%28v=vs.85%29.aspx).  You cannot reliably use VirtualQueryEx() for a 64-bit process in a 32-bit program.

Comment: So, `VirtualQueryEx` is not considered as a debugger? The documentation looks ambiguous :(

Answer (score 2, accepted):

So, all in all I was just a noob and it was solved with a simple test:

`VirtualQueryEx` fails with error **24** (ERROR_BAD_LENGTH) if I try to use `MEMORY_BASIC_INFORMATION32` instead of `MEMORY_BASIC_INFORMATION`

The answer is, **ALWAYS USE `MEMORY_BASIC_INFORMATION`**.

This is how I am calling `VirtualQueryEx`

```
MEMORY_BASIC_INFORMATION32 info32;
SIZE_T r32 = VirtualQueryEx(hndl,
                            (void *) 0x0,
                            (PMEMORY_BASIC_INFORMATION) &info32,
                            sizeof(info32));
```

Comment: This cannot be right because how could you target memory in a 64 bit process when you use 32 bit pointers? The answer that you linked to is correct (and tells you not to do this). (My answer was wrong - deleted).

Comment: Keep in mind that this question ask whether there's a problem if the TARGET is 32 bits (the source process is 64 bits), so there's no problem with pointer sizes.

Comment: Right. In the other direction it would be a problem.